# SQL conditional SELECT with possible NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've tried searching for this on stackoverflow but I can't find the answer.

I'm simplifying my problem so it reads easier, I'll expand if necessary.

I've got a Employee SQL table with `NAME, ADDRESS, HIRE_DATE` and we recently added a `REHIRE_DATE` to keep track of when new employees restart with the company. I'd like to write a SQL search to pull the `NAME, ADDRESS` and their most recent hire date. If they're a rehire I'd use the `REHIRE_DATE` field but if they're original use the `HIRE_DATE` field. I'm guessing it's a `CASE` statement that's looking for a `NULL` in the `REHIRE_DATE` field but beyond that I'm lost.

Comment: Maybe you could add a small sample data set and the output you expect?

Comment: This is not related to your question, but you may want to consider storing hire dates in a separate table e.g. `EmploymentPeriod (EmployeeID (FK), StartDate, EndDate)`. With your current configuration if an employee restarts for a third time there is nowhere to store the rehire date without losing the last rehire date. If you use a one to many table relationship they can leave and come back as many times as they like without causing database problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should produce the results you want:

```
SELECT Name
    , Address
    , CASE WHEN REHIRE_DATE IS NULL THEN HIRE_DATE ELSE REHIRE_DATE END
FROM Employee
```

This checks if the Rehire Date, if it is `NULL` then you will get the Hire Date if it isn't then you will return the Rehire Date.

Comment: That's perfect. I was hung up on using '=NULL' and not 'IS NULL'.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot use `=NULL` you have to use `IS NULL` :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit more clear to use the `ISNULL` function? `ISNULL(REHIRE_DATE, HIRE_DATE)` is exactly what you're doing here.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore you can use either, I just used `CASE` for my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think all you need to do is this:

```
SELECT
    NAME
    , ADDRESS
    , ISNULL(REHIRE_DATE, HIRE_DATE) AS MostRecentHireDate
FROM Employee
```

In this case the rehire date should always be greater than the hire date if it is filled out (You can't get **re**-hired before you get hired. So you just always want to take the rehire date unless it is null, at which point you take the hire date. Sound good?

Answer (score 0):

Better still, use IFNULL():

```
SELECT IFNULL(REHIRE_DATE,HIRE_DATE) FROM Employee
```

Comment: `IFNULL` is not valid SQL-Server syntax. `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` would both work though. There is a good answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4277/7257) explaining the difference between the two.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the tag, and the question didn't specify. IFNULL() is what I use every day in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could also  use the coalesce() function and do it this way

```
select name, address, coalesce(rehire_date,hire_date) from table_name
```

if the first value is null it will go to the second value

Comment: If both values are not null, you will get both returned.

Comment: I know this is old, but for others googling that get to this: if both values are not null you will not get both returned, you will still only get the first non-null result. That's how [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) works in SQL Server.